# sqlite: updating a table columns with columns coming from the cat of 2 other tables columns

Tags: sqlite, sql-update

May be a trivial question, I looked in various archive but could not find my way.

A streamlined example of my situation.

I got a table t with a column i I want to update with values coming from 2 other table u and v column i. To achieve this I use a intermediate table x like this.

```
create table t (i integer);
create table u (i integer);
create table v (i integer);

insert into t values (11);
insert into t values (12);
insert into t values (13);
insert into t values (14);


insert into u values (21);
insert into u values (22);

insert into v values (31);
insert into v values (32);

create table x as select * from u union all select * from v;

select rowid,* from x
rowid i
----- --
1     21
2     22
3     31
4     32

update t set i=(select * from x where rowid=t.rowid );

select rowid,* from t;
rowid i
----- --
1     21
2     22
3     31
4     32
```

It happen that I know that card(t)=card(u)+car(v). I try to get rid of this intermediate x table.

I reset t to 11,12,13,14 then

```
update t set i=(select * from u union all select * from v)
where rowid=t.rowid;

select rowid,* from t"
rowid i
----- --
1     21
2     21
3     21
4     21
```

Ouch, I double check with a select instead of an update.

```
select rowid,* from (select * from u union all select * from v)"
rowid i
----- --
      21
      22
      31
      32
```

Ha no rowid for subselect. On the other hand I know how to generate a number serie

```
with recursive s as
(select 1 as n union all select n+1 from s where n<4)
select n from s;
n
-----
1
2
3
4
```

But I don't see how I could combine this things to achieve what I can do with the x table, is that doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there are no gaps in the `rowid` values, you can construct the sequence by adding the appropriate offset to the values from the second table:

```
> SELECT rowid,                            i FROM u
  UNION ALL
  SELECT rowid + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM u), i FROM v;
rowid  i
-----  --
1      21
2      22
3      31
4      32
```

You can then use this as a source for the update:

```
WITH x(rowid, i) AS (
    ...
)
UPDATE t
SET i = (SELECT i FROM x
         WHERE rowid = t.rowid);
```

Comment: Yes no gap in rowid, cardinality are in sync as well, and I can derive your example with more than 2 tables. Perfect :)